# How to serve static files via Rack?

Tags: ruby, file, static, rack

I am currently developing a Rack-based application and want to redirect all file requests (e.g. `filename.filetype`) to a specified folder.

`Rack::Static` only supports file requests for a special folder(e.g. "/media").

Do I have to write my own Rack middleware or does an out-of-the-box solution exist?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To redirect every request to a particular path, use [`Rack::File`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/File.html) (for some reason this class is absent in recent documentation, but it is [still part of](http://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/file.rb) the latest Rack):

```
run Rack::File.new("/my/path")
```

To redirect every request, and add an HTML index of all files in the target dir, use [`Rack::Directory`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Directory.html):

```
run Rack::Directory.new("/my/path")
```

To combine several directories or serve only a some requests from the target dir:

```
map "/url/prefix" do
  run Rack::File.new("/my/path")
end

# More calls to map if necessary...

# All other requests.
run MyApp.new
```

Comment: I had to wrap the run MyApp.new with map "/" do .. end. Otherwise I was getting an undefined call method error. (No idea why.)

Answer (score 14):

An update, the latest Rack implementation allows you to use [Rack::Static](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Static)

Example:

```
use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/media"]
```

Will serve all static resources under `./media` folder relative to `config.ru` location.

Answer (score 11):

You might be able to use `Rack::File` directly. Here's a `config.ru` file you can plug into rackup to see it work:

```
app = proc do |env|
  Rack::File.new('foo/bar').call(env)
end

run app
```

Answer (score 2):

```
run Rack::Directory.new(Dir.pwd)
```