# Ruby Rack - mounting a simple web server that reads index.html as default

Tags: ruby, indexing, webserver, config, rack

I'm trying to get some information from this tutorial: http://m.onkey.org/2008/11/18/ruby-on-rack-2-rack-builder

basically I want to have a file `config.ru` that tell rack to read the current directory so I can access all the files just like a simple apache server and also read the default root with the index.html file...is there any way to do it?

my current `config.ru` looks like this:

```
run Rack::Directory.new('')
#this would read the directory but it doesn't set the root to index.html


map '/' do
  file = File.read('index.html')
  run Proc.new {|env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, file] }
end
#using this reads the index.html mapped as the root but ignores the other files in the directory
```

So I don't know how to proceed from here...

I've also tried this following the tutorials example but `thin` doesn't starts properly.

```
builder = Rack::Builder.new do

  run Rack::Directory.new('')

  map '/' do
    file = File.read('index.html')
    run Proc.new {|env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, file] }
  end

end

Rack::Handler::Thin.run builder, :port => 3000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW, `:port => 3000` should be `:Port => 3000` -- note the capital "P" in Port.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think that you are missing the the rackup command. Here is how it is used:

```
rackup config.ru
```

This is going to run your rack app on port 9292 using webrick. You can read "rackup --help" for more info how you can change these defaults.

About the app that you want to create. Here is how I think it should look like:

```
# This is the root of our app
@root = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

run Proc.new { |env|
  # Extract the requested path from the request
  path = Rack::Utils.unescape(env['PATH_INFO'])
  index_file = @root + "#{path}/index.html"

  if File.exists?(index_file)
    # Return the index
    [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, File.read(index_file)]
    # NOTE: using Ruby >= 1.9, third argument needs to respond to :each
    # [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, [File.read(index_file)]]
  else
    # Pass the request to the directory app
    Rack::Directory.new(@root).call(env)
  end
}
```

Comment: very good, that's exactly what I wanted to achieve, I think I can obtain more information from here and learn more about it. Thanks a lot valo

Comment: Found this by chance and just thought I'd add this in: [REQUEST_PATH is a legacy variable that is completely undefined in Rack.](http://groups.google.com/group/rack-devel/browse_thread/thread/0a41ecc3ce2db50d)

Comment: Thanks! To build on what @Teddy said, use `PATH_INFO` and not `REQUEST_PATH`. Submitted an edit request with that change.

Comment: WARNING: dont use this in a production application!

You can simply read any file on the whole server, since the code does NOT check if the resulting file is contained within @root. Simply do 
GET /../../../../etc/passwd

and you get /etc/passwd (well, you'll have to try on the number of ".." entries)

Comment: The rack spec requires that the body response be an Array. This works like a charm just make sure to do : `[File.read(index_file)]` as the response's third element.

Comment: @MichaelSiebert: Using `..` in a path segment causes both Thin and WEBrick to return `400 Bad Request` (if the `..` is at the beginning of the path) or `403 Forbidden` (if it's not at the beginning).

Comment: @superjadex12 - The body response should respond to `each`, it needn't be an Array.

Comment: @Swanand ah thanks! Didn't know that =) I'm learning the essence of 'duck typing' in all sorts of ways =p

Comment: You could use a lambda too like a lot of code examples in the Rack lib show. run lambda {|env| Rack::Directory.new(@root).call(env)}

Answer (score 11):

I ended up on this page looking for a one liner...

If all you want is to serve the current directory for a few one-off tasks, this is all you need:

```
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 5000
```

Details on how it works:  http://www.benjaminoakes.com/2013/09/13/ruby-simple-http-server-minimalist-rake/

Comment: This was an outstanding post and should have the highest count on this post.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using Rack::Static

```
map "/foo" do
  use Rack::Static, 
    :urls => [""], :root => File.expand_path('bar'), :index => 'index.html'
  run lambda {|*|}
end
```

Comment: this has solved a massive issue I was experiencing with static files under Sinatra. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For me, using Ruby 2.0 and Rack 1.5.2, [sinm solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744018/753737) worked for serving the index page (both as default page for root and loaded explicitly), but for other files I obtained errors similar to the following:

```
Rack::Lint::LintError: Status must be >=100 seen as integer
```

I combined sinm solution with this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2271193/753737) and the snippet found on [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby#file-server-configuration) to obtain the desired behavior (assuming that the entire site is contained in a folder called `public`):

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public",
  :index => 'index.html'

run Rack::File.new("public")
```

Answer (score 2):

My example for doing the exact same below:

```
module Rack
  class DirectoryIndex
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end
    def call(env)
      index_path = ::File.join($documentRoot, Rack::Request.new(env).path.split('/'), 'index.html')
      if ::File.exists?(index_path)
        return [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, [::File.read(index_path)]]
      else
        @app.call(env)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'rack_directory_index.rb'

$documentRoot = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'build'))

Capybara.app = Rack::Builder.new do |builder|
puts "Creating static rack server serving #{$documentRoot}"
use Rack::DirectoryIndex
    run Rack::Directory.new($documentRoot)
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.run_server = true
end
```

The solution is mostly a copy and paste from different answers but it works fine. You can find it as a [**gist here aswell**](https://gist.github.com/kurtsson/75a17499fb2d90687438), good luck

Comment: Please enhance your answer with some information from your link. Answers should not only consist of a link