# How to serve static content from gems in Sinatra (analagous to Rails ::ActionDispatch::Static)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sinatra, actiondispatch

I have a Sinatra service which includes a gem.  The gem contains some static content which I would like to include in and serve via the Sinatra app.

In Rails this would be done with ActionDispatch. Here is an example:
http://jonswope.com/2010/07/25/rails-3-engines-plugins-and-static-assets/

Is there a way to do this in Sinatra without ActionDispatch? 
Or is there a clean way to do it via ActionDispatch in Sinatra?

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra is Rack Applications. An easy way to serve static files is with [Rack::Static](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Static.html). More examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265036/how-to-serve-static-files-via-rack) SO question.