# Rack app, redirect everything to root

Tags: ruby, rack

I just deployed a static page to Heroku as a static rack app. My config.ru:

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/stylesheets", "/images"],
  :root => "public",
  :index => "public/index.html"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Now I want to redirect all request to this static index.html file. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265036/how-to-serve-static-files-via-rack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually worked from the beginning. I just had to adjust the paths to my images and CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the call to "use" the middleware Rack::Static, all requests will render index.html. Although you probably have to write

```
File.open('public/index.html').read
```

instead of

```
File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
```

Comment: If I do this my images and CSS files are not loaded.

Comment: .. sorry for the confusion, I thought this is what you want.