# How to mount static files for Rack

Tags: ruby, file, rack, thin

I want to serv static files as well as dynamic contents through Rack. Previously, I used WEBrick **without using Rack**, with code like this, and it worked:

```
    @s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
        Port: 3000,
        BindAddress: "localhost",
        Logger: WEBrick::Log.new(File::NULL),
        AccessLog: [nil, nil]
    )
    %w[INT TERM].each{|signal| trap(signal){@s.shutdown}}
    @s.mount("/", self)
    @s.mount("/resource/", WEBrick::HTTPServlet::FileHandler, "/")
    @s.start
```

In the above, requests to `localhost:3000` will be responded by dynamic contents, and requests to `localhost:3000/resource/path_to_file` will be responded by a static file located at `/path_to_file` on my computer.

Now, I want to switch to a system using Rack with Thin server. I wrote the following, but could not get the static files served. How should it be changed to make it work?

```
    Rack::Handler::Thin.run(->env{
        h = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env["QUERY_STRING"])
        # I tried the following three lines one at a time, but neither worked.
        use(Rack::Static, urls: "/resource/", root: "/") # First try
        Rack::File.new("/resource").call(env) # Second try
        Rack::Directory.new("/resource").call(env) # Third try
        [200, {}, [some_dyamically_generated_content]]
    }, Port: 3000)
```

I know that ther is a similar question: [How to serve static files via Rack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265036), but I could not make it work. I am not sure how to use `Rack::Static`, `Rack::File`, or `Rack::Directory`. Please teach me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`Rack::Builder`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Builder.html) in order to use the `use SomeMiddleware` syntax in a normal Ruby script (it's normally used in a `config.ru` file). You also need `run` for your application. Note that the `urls` key to `Rack::Static` takes an array, not a single string:

```
require 'rack'
Rack::Handler::Thin.run(Rack::Builder.new {
    use(Rack::Static, urls: ["/resource/"], root: "/")
    run ->env{[200, {}, [some_dyamically_generated_content]]}
}, Port: 3000)
```

Here `Rack::Builder` is taking your application, `->env{[200, {}, [some_dyamically_generated_content]]}`, adding the `Rack::Static` middleware to it and creating a new combined application which is then passed to Thin to run.

`Rack::Static` is a middleware component that you can add to existing rack applications. `Rack::File` and `Rack::Directory` are both themselves rack applications, not middleware (`Rack::Static` uses `Rack::File` internally, as does `Rack::Directory` by default). You could achieve the same effect as above using `Rack::File` and the `map` command:

```
require 'rack'
Rack::Handler::Thin.run(Rack::Builder.new {
    map "/resource/" do
      run Rack::File.new "/"
    end
    map "/" do
      run ->env{[200, {}, [some_dyamically_generated_content]]}
    end
}, Port: 3000)
```

The more common way to do this would be to put the contents of the block passed to `Rack::Bundler.new` in a `config.ru` file:

```
use(Rack::Static, urls: ["/resource/"], root: "/") 
run ->env{[200, {}, [some_dyamically_generated_content]]}
```

You can then run this with `thin start`, which should find `config.ru` if run from the same directory, or you can use the `-R` option to specify the file. The `rackup` command can also be used, `rackup -s thin` if you want to specify Thin as the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require authentication/authorization before serving the files you should be able to add files into `/public` and have them be served by the underlying server.
So if your app layout looks like this

```
my_app/
  - app.rb
  - config.ru
  - public/
    - a_static_file.png
    - another_static_file.png
```

Once you start your app (using thin, webrick, or apache or whatever underlying server) you can access the static files from `http://localhost:4567/a_static_file.png`

Comment: I might look into that, but now, I need access to certain locations without having them all moved to `/public`. Thanks for the help.