# Rack middleware serve static folders from submodule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Rack (on rails) question:

Given I am loading a submodule into my Rails app,
And I want to serve static files from submodule's `{folder_a, folder_b}`

I cannot move the submodule's folder into `/public`, because I only want
to serve some of the files from the submodule (and not all)

How do I configure Rack to do that?

My structure looks like this:

```
config.ru
submodule/public/folder_a/
submodule/public/folder_b/
public/
```

And I want the following mapping

```
submodule/public/folder_a => http://localhost:3000/folder_a
submodule/public/folder_b => http://localhost:3000/folder_b
```

What I tried so far:

```
use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/folder_a", "folder_b"], :root => "submodule/public"
```

That did not work, just no response on `/folder_a` from my server. This idea was partly taken from the (old) question [How to serve static files via Rack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265036/how-to-serve-static-files-via-rack), but it seems to suggest old resolutions which fails (currently my project is using Rack 1.5.2).

I also tried just symlinking my desired folders into /public, which works. 
But I am sure it will be prettier and more elegant to use Rack directly

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't provide full help, but I think I remember using `Rack::Directory` for such a purpose. Did you had a look at it?

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire, yeah, I found an example but it turned out to be outdated. Could not get it to work. Was it failing with `Rack::Directory.new` does not exist??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the working directory might be messed with depending on how your Rails application is launched.

I got it working inside a Rails applicaiton with the following config.ru:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/folder_a", "/folder_b"], :root => ::File.expand_path("submodule/public")

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

Then in a terminal:

```
$ rails server -d
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

$ curl http://0.0.0.0:3000/folder_a/index.html
A

$ curl http://0.0.0.0:3000/folder_b/index.html
B
```

Comment: looks good, seems odd though that you have to do the File.expand_path.  Main difference from my (failing) example: The preprended slash in `"/folder_a"`